# Eigen Matrix Assignment Operator with User-Defined Data Types

Tags: templates, c++14, eigen, complex-numbers, ceres-solver

I am using the Eigen matrix library to deal with matrices of `std::complex<T>` data types, where `T` is either of type `double` or of type `ceres::Jet<double,...>`. Eigen documentation indicates that `<<` is the correct operator to use for assignment, but it seems that `<<` is not overloaded for matrices of user-defined data types. Is there a different method I can use to initialize Eigen matrices that works for both data types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is not that Eigen is not overloaded for matrices of user-defined type (it is) but that you have a **nested template argument** of the type `Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<T>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>` (where `T` is something like `ceres::Jet<double>` resulting in `Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<ceres::Jet<double>>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>`). You will have to **explicitly construct the elements of the nested type `T` before using the streaming operator `<<`**.

```
Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<T>, 3, 1> mat;
mat << T{1.0}, T{2.0}, T{3.0};
```

---

**More detailed explanation**

To further explain this let's start with a simple class we will use for the element type

```
class SomeClass {
  public:
    constexpr SomeClass(double const& some_data = 0.0) noexcept
      : some_data{some_data} {
      return;
    }

  private:
    double some_data;
};
```

A matrix of this user-defined type can be successfully assigned with:

```
Eigen::Matrix<SomeClass, 3, 1> mat;
mat << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0;
```

The problem only emerges if you apply it to nested element types such as `std::complex<SomeClass>`. We would like to use the [following overload](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a0e575eb0ba6cc6bc5f347872abd8509d):

```
CommaInitializer<Derived> Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::operator<<(const Scalar& s)
```

where [**`Scalar` is the type of the matrix coefficients**](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#title10) (element type, e.g. `Derived = Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<T>, 3, 1>` and `Scalar = std::complex<T>`):

```
Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::Scalar
```

Therefore when compiling GCC will tell you that it can't match the template:

```
note: candidate: Eigen::CommaInitializer<Derived> Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::operator<<(const Scalar&) [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<SomeClass>, 3, 1>; Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::Scalar = std::complex<SomeClass>
inline CommaInitializer<Derived> DenseBase<Derived>::operator<< (const Scalar& s)

note: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘double’ to ‘const Scalar& {aka const std::complex<SomeClass>&}’
```

What you will have to do to make it compile is to **construct the elements with a type which can be converted to `Scalar`** and can then call the corresponding streaming operator as follows:

```
mat << std::complex<SomeClass>{SomeClass{1.0}}, std::complex<SomeClass>{SomeClass{2.0}}, std::complex<SomeClass>{SomeClass{3.0}};

mat << std::complex<SomeClass>{1.0}, std::complex<SomeClass>{2.0}, std::complex<SomeClass>{3.0};

mat << SomeClass{1.0}, SomeClass{2.0}, SomeClass{3.0};
```

This should be avoidable by changing the Eigen library to something like

```
CommaInitializer<Derived> Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::operator<<(Elem const& s)
```

and require with [`std::enable_if_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) or [C++20 concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) that `Scalar` [can be constructed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) by an element of type `Elem`:

```
std::is_constructible_v<Scalar, Elem>
```

If you really need you could try to write an overload for it yourself that makes sure that `std::is_constructible_v<Scalar, Elem>` but `!std::is_same_v<Scalar, Elem>` but I personally think it is never a good idea to add such a functionality to an existing library yourself. Somebody else copying fragments of your code and expecting them to work might end up with not working code.

---

**Alternative options for assignments**

As alternatives to assignment with `<<` you could

- Use its [**constructor**](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html#title3)
- [Initialise the Eigen matrix from an **existing** C-style **array**, `std::array` or `std::vector`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html#title4) or
- Use its [**coefficient accessors**](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html#title4).

For the first two options you will have to use the same logic as discussed in the previous paragraph or use **double braces**

```
Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<SomeClass>, 3, 1> mat = { {1.0, 2.0}, {2.0, 3.0}, {3.0, 4.0} };
```

or

```
std::vector<std::complex<SomeClass>> vec = { {1.0, 2.0}, {2.0, 3.0}, {3.0, 4.0} };
Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<SomeClass>, 3, 1> mat{vec.data()};
```

while something like

```
mat(0,0) = 1.0;

mat(0,0) = {1.0, 2.0};
```

will create a complex element with a real part `1.0` and imaginary part `0.0` or `2.0` of type `SomeClass` without having to call the constructor `SomeClass{}` explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I would have to construct the elements of type `std::complex<T>` explicitly? Something like `std::complex<T>((T) 1.0, (T) 2.0)` for each element?

Comment: @maksel You are welcome! Yes, if you want to use the `<<` operator (`std::complex<T>{1.0, 2.0}` is sufficient).

Comment: Will something like `const std::complex<T> one = std::complex<T>(1.0, 0.0);` work, even for `Jet<double, ...>` objects? I don't have to cast 1.0 an 0.0 to `T` type?

Comment: Moreover, can Ceres perform AD through complex numbers?

Comment: @maksel For Ceres you are right, you can only do something like `std::vector<std::complex<ceres::Jet<double,2>>> vec = { {ceres::Jet<double,2>{1.0}, ceres::Jet<double,2>{2.0}}, {ceres::Jet<double,2>{4.0}, ceres::Jet<double,2>{5.0}} };` and initialise the Eigen matrix from this vector or you indeed have to cast to type `ceres::Jet<double,2>`: `mat << std::complex<ceres::Jet<double,2>>{ceres::Jet<double,2>{1.0}, ceres::Jet<double,2>{2.0}}, std::complex<ceres::Jet<double,2>>{ceres::Jet<double,2>{2.0}} };` as its constructor is marked as `explicit`.

Comment: It is quite annoying to write, I agree but at least it works. For automatic derivatives through complex numbers I do not really understand how you want to do that. Maybe you can supply an example.

Comment: My final vector of residuals is complex, and I was hoping to convert that to a real vector of double the length (so I would be considering all real residuals). I just wanted to make sure such operations would be handled by `Ceres` AD properly.

Comment: @maksel I am still not sure how precisely this would supposed to work. Please provide some more information. Furthermore does my post answer your question regarding the initialisation or do you need some more information?

Comment: Hello, yes, I got the initialization working (and I think I figured out the other issues in the code). I appreciate your help with this matter!

Comment: @maksel Excellent, I am very glad to hear that!